# How to set table view footer color to be the same as navigation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I tried this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.tableView.bounds.size.height - kCustomRowHeight, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, kCustomRowHeight);
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame];
    footerView.backgroundColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor;
    return footerView;
}
```

But that makes the footer view invisible.

But this works:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGRect footerFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.tableView.bounds.size.height - kCustomRowHeight, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, kCustomRowHeight);
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerFrame];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return footerView;
}
```

So how can I make the footer have the same background color as the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a real pain why you try to read navigationController properties, and I do not understand why the `footerView` is invisible. Nevertheless, for your current problem... why dont you try replicating the color by setting your own RGB with `alpha` values  ?